# Verification of an inequality involving $|x|^\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations

Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$, $\alpha>0$ and $w(x)=|x|^\alpha.$ Then this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S089812211830052X?casa_token=7qZzdd0VNkgAAAAA:jfqeipAT44VjnrieYu0dHtiIg-LQVAJ-0F0tmkvQ5bcpJaA02mdMJcv45l3_6FOcYOpyai7ucQg#fd1.1) I am reading has the following claim,

$$\nabla^2\log w(\nabla u,\nabla u)+\frac{(\nabla \log w\cdot \nabla u)^2}{\alpha}\leq 0.$$

I am trying to check if this inequality indeed holds. I first computed

$$\frac{(\nabla \log w\cdot \nabla u)^2}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{|x|^4}(x\cdot \nabla u)^2$$

since

$$\nabla\log w = \frac{\alpha}{|x|^2} x.$$

I am guessing that (the authors did not define this in the paper)

$$\nabla^2\log w(\nabla u,\nabla u)=\sum_{i,j}D_{ij}\log wD_iuD_ju$$

where $D_i u$ is the partial derivative wrt to $x_i$ of $u.$  This gives me

$$\nabla^2\log w(\nabla u,\nabla u)=\frac{\alpha |\nabla u|^2}{|x|^2}-\frac{2\alpha (x\cdot \nabla u)^2}{|x|^4}$$

since

$$D_{ij}\log w = \frac{\alpha}{|x|^2}\delta_{ij}-\frac{2\alpha}{|x|^4}x_i x_j.$$

Therefore,
$$\nabla^2\log w(\nabla u,\nabla u)+\frac{(\nabla \log w\cdot \nabla u)^2}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha |\nabla u|^2}{|x|^2}-\frac{\alpha (x\cdot \nabla u)^2}{|x|^4}\\
=\frac{\alpha |\nabla u|^2}{|x|^2}\left(1-\cos^2(\theta_x)\right)\geq 0,$$

where $\theta_x$ is the angle between $x$ and the gradient of $u$, however, this contradicts the claim in the paper. Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: your paper makes this inequality as an assumption in the overdetermined Poisson formulation in $(1.1).$ Are you sure you proved it right? I am not following the notation for $\log w(\cdot, \cdot)$

Comment: @dezdichado I think that $\nabla^2 \log w(\nabla u,\nabla u) = \langle \nabla^2 \log w \nabla u,  \nabla u \rangle.$